# how to get permissions to post message on facebook wall for testing purpose?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would just like to test posting messages on my facebook wall, I created an app and a test app, but when I login it says "this app cannot post on facebook" - do I already have to request those permissions even if I would just like to test it?

Under Status & Review I found "approved items" - I added publish pages but it asks me questions which I can't answer because the app is clearly not working yet so I doubt it will get approved.

Comment: Of course you have to request the permission from the user you are testing this with.

Comment: Yea thanks to WizKid's answer I figured it out, I thought everything has to be set on the application and that I have to approve it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to get it approved. You can ask anyone that have a role on the app (admins, developers and testers) for any permission even if it is not approved